# 'Line2D' object has no property 'ylabel' error with pd.plot()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

I am trying to plot using `df.plot` from the pandas plotting library, and was using the following code:

```
df_mean.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, layout=(1,8), figsize=(40,8), 
         sharey=True, ylabel = "Percent Change", title="Average movement")
```

I thought it might have something to do with using `np.transpose()` since it would convert it into a numpy array, but after conversion back to a `pd.DataFrame()`, the error still persists.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-85f6c80ca026> in <module>
      1 df_mean = pd.DataFrame(df_mean)
      2 
----> 3 df_mean.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, layout=(1,8), figsize=(40,8), 
      4              title="Average movement",
      5              sharey=True, ylabel = "Percent Change")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, 
**kwargs)
    845             keyword_args = ", ".join(
    846                 f"{name}={repr(value)}" for (name, default), value in 
zip(arg_def, args)
--> 847             )
    848             msg = (
    849                 "`Series.plot()` should not be called with positional "

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py in plot(data, 
kind, **kwargs)
     59             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     60     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 61     plot_obj.generate()
     62     plot_obj.draw()
     63     return plot_obj.result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in generate(self)
    261         else:
    262             return self.data.shape[1]
--> 263 
    264     def draw(self):
    265         self.plt.draw_if_interactive()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in 
_make_plot(self)
   1075             self.data = self.data.fillna(value=0)
   1076         self.x_compat = plot_params["x_compat"]
-> 1077         if "x_compat" in self.kwds:
   1078             self.x_compat = bool(self.kwds.pop("x_compat"))
   1079 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _plot(cls, ax, 
x, y, style, column_num, stacking_id, **kwds)
   1102 
   1103         stacking_id = self._get_stacking_id()
-> 1104         is_errorbar = com.any_not_none(*self.errors.values())
   1105 
   1106         colors = self._get_colors()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\converter.py in 
wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     64         with pandas_converters():
     65             return func(*args, **kwargs)
---> 66 
     67     return wrapper
     68 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _plot(cls, ax, 
x, y, style, is_errorbar, **kwds)
    654 
    655         if is_errorbar:
--> 656             if "xerr" in kwds:
    657                 kwds["xerr"] = np.array(kwds.get("xerr"))
    658             if "yerr" in kwds:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, 
scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1741         
   1742         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1743         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1744         for line in lines:
   1745             self.add_line(line)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, data, 
*args, **kwargs)
    271                 this += args[0],
    272                 args = args[1:]
--> 273             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    274 
    275     def get_next_color(self):

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, 
kwargs)
    416         if ncx > 1 and ncy > 1 and ncx != ncy:
    417             raise ValueError(f"x has {ncx} columns but y has {ncy} 
columns")
--> 418         return [func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
    419                 for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
    420 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    416         if ncx > 1 and ncy > 1 and ncx != ncy:
    417             raise ValueError(f"x has {ncx} columns but y has {ncy} 
 columns")
--> 418         return [func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
    419                 for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
    420 

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _makeline(self, x, y, 
kw, kwargs)
    310         default_dict = self._getdefaults(set(), kw)
    311         self._setdefaults(default_dict, kw)
--> 312         seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
    313         return seg
    314 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in __init__(self, xdata, ydata, 
linewidth, linestyle, color, marker, markersize, markeredgewidth, markeredgecolor, 
markerfacecolor, markerfacecoloralt, fillstyle, antialiased, dash_capstyle, 
solid_capstyle, dash_joinstyle, solid_joinstyle, pickradius, drawstyle, markevery, 
**kwargs)
    388         # update kwargs before updating data to give the caller a
    389         # chance to init axes (and hence unit support)
--> 390         self.update(kwargs)
    391         self.pickradius = pickradius
    392         self.ind_offset = 0

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in update(self, props)
     994                     func = getattr(self, f"set_{k}", None)
     995                     if not callable(func):
 --> 996                         raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} 
object "
    997                                              f"has no property {k!r}")
    998                     ret.append(func(v))

AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'ylabel'
```

I was able to run this code fine on my mac, but when I transferred it over to my desktop, I get this error, and I'm not sure why. I thought it could be a version problem, but I updated pandas and it didn't fix anything.

Anybody have an idea what could be causing something like this?

Comment: Update pandas, you must! `ylabel` is only available from `pandas 1.1.0`. Also `kind='line'` is the default, so you don't need to include it. Check `pd.__version__`

Comment: To add to @TrentonMcKinney comment about checking `pd.__version__`. This when ran from your script/notebook will print the version of `pandas` which throws this error. It's possible that you updated your system's version of `pandas` and not anaconda's.

Comment: @Jason That's what happened I think. I wasn't aware I needed to update Anaconda with it as well, so thank you for pointing this out! Fixed it all :)

Comment: @Falcon I'm glad you managed to fix your problem. The system and anaconda packages are separate from one another. So in future you only need to update your conda environment (if that's where you're running your script/notebook from). `which python` will show you the path to where the python you're using is located. If you search for 'python virtual environments' it'll explain what I can't fit into a comment.

Comment: So at the anaconda prompt, do `conda update -all`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick:

If the `ylabel` parameter is the problem, remove it and set it directly to `ax`.

```
ax = df_mean.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, layout=(1,8), figsize=(40,8), 
         sharey=True, title="Average movement")
ax.set_ylabel('Percent Change')
plt.show()
```